# how to limit file manager access based on users on Ajenti

Tags: ubuntu, files

I installed Ajenti-v on my ubuntu server 15.10 and I want to create multiple users with specific access to their home directory.

currently, whenever I create a new ajenti user (which is synced with OS Users), it can access to the whole file system.

How can I limit their access to a specific directory like /home/user?

There is an option within the Configure > Plugins section of the root user which will limit the access on all users's file managers, but it cannot be used for specifying directories for each users.

Comment: You could just make them not privileged to acsess the whole file system, then just do 'chown -R user /home/user && chmod -R u+rwx /home/user' where user is the username of the user.

Comment: @John I've already done that before, but doesn't make any difference in ajenti.